# Read DOM objects from c# controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know if there is any native way in .net core 6 or higher to interact with the html page (a view for example -.cshtml file-).
Samples of this could be, create a table row  , change the id of a , read the inner html of an element. etc... This kind of things that yoy can do using Jscript, for example.
The thing is that I need to create rows in a table, delete them and read the values of the inputs inside the rows. I did this using Jscript and it works, but I was wondering if there is a better way.
Thanks for any response

This is what I did

....

##### Asignar roles

```
                <table id="tbRol" class="panel-body-grid izd-5">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:150px">Aplicación</th>

                            <th style="width:150px">Rol</th>


                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select id="txtAppId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.APLICACIONID"></select></td>
                            <td><select id="txtRolId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ROLID"></select></td>

                            <td style="width:60px;"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Nuevo" /></td>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" id="btnDel" value="Eliminar" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <br />
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" id="btnSave" value="Guardar Roles" />
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" asp-route-id="@Model.USUARIO.ID" asp-action="DeleteRoles">Eliminar todos los roles</a>
                <p id="msg"></p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        let roles = new Array();
        let anteriores = new Array();


        $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
            //Reference the  TextBoxes.

            var txtAppId = $("#txtAppId");
            var txtRolId = $("#txtRolId");
            $("#msg").html("");

            //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
            var tBody = $("#tbRol > TBODY")[0];

            //Check the inserted value

            if (anteriores.indexOf(txtAppId.val()) == -1 && !(txtAppId.val() == null || txtRolId.val() == null)) {
                //Add Row.
                var rol = {};
                var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
                rolx = rol;

                //Add  cell.
                cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
                cell.html($('#txtAppId option:selected').text());
                rol.AppId = parseInt(txtAppId.val());

                //Add  cell.
                cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
                cell.html($('#txtRolId option:selected').text());
                rol.RolId = parseInt(txtRolId.val());
                //cell.html(txtRolId.val());

                rol.UId = parseInt("@Model.USUARIO.ID");
                //Add element to array
                anteriores.push(txtAppId.val());
                roles.push(rol);

                //Clear the TextBoxes.
                txtAppId.val("");
                txtRolId.val("");
            }
            else $("#msg").html("No se puede ingresar dos veces el mismo valor ni ingresar valores en blanco");

        });
        $("body").on("click", "#btnDel", function () {
            //Reference the  TextBoxes.

            var txtAppId = $("#txtAppId");
            var txtRolId = $("#txtRolId");

            $("#msg").html("");
            //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
            var tBody = $("#tbRol > TBODY")[0];

            //Delete Row.
            var row = tBody.deleteRow(-1);


            //Delete element of array
            roles.pop();
            anteriores.pop();

        });


        $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {


            //Populate  data
            var rolVM = {};
            rolVM = roles;

            //console.log(rolVM);

            //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
            //data: JSON.stringify(rolVM),
            //$.post("/USUARIO/InsertRoles", rolVM);
            
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("InsertRoles")",
                data: JSON.stringify(rolVM),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async:false,
                success: function (r) {
                    $("#msg").html(rolVM.length + " Roles Insertados");

                }
            });
            
            if (rolVM.length > 0) {
                $("#msg").attr("class", "label-success");
                $("#msg").html(rolVM.length + " Roles Insertados");
                console.log(" Roles Insertados");
            }
            else {
                $("#msg").attr("class", "label-warning");
                $("#msg").html(rolVM.length + " Roles Insertados");
                console.log(" Roles no Insertados");
            }
            console.log(rolVM);
            window.location.reload(true);

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I think you fundamentally misunderstand how the server and browser are two different things. Your server code does not know about the DOM at all, it just sends out strings which a browser can interpret as HTML and create a DOM. You could try Blazor in the browser, but quite frankly, I'd stick with JAvascript.

Comment: Better? No. But if you dislike Javascript you may try using Typescript.

Comment: All you can do is JS code that will listen for commands from server (sent via Ajax) and do the appropriate things with DOM. I however do not recommend such approach because there should certainly be a better solution for what you want to do. It will probably overwhelm your server (send commands in real time to all clients + handle requests?!) and at least is inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I understand that the way is JS, I don´t dislike  JS either. But may be I thought ther was some asp helpers, or something else I was missing,  that could avoid using JS. I understand for your comments that the way is JS, or TypeScript.